# How to select data from pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, series

So far I've used pandas dataframe, but now I have a series, and I can't find how to select data from it. I have the series:

```
bp00096    885
bp2015     740
bp2012     529
```

How can I select both the numbers, and the names?
by writing `my_series[]` I can get the numbers, but how can I select the name corresponding to it? 
I'm using python 3.4

Comment: How working `s.loc['bp2015']` ?

Comment: No, Not working

Comment: There is error? What is `my_series.head().to_dict()` ?

Comment: Apology, that is working, gives me the corresponding number. Is there a way to select the column of the names, without mentioning them specifically? like in dataframes?

Comment: Series have no columns, bur names. So `s.name` should working.